# capture session id in spring websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

My `WebSocketConfig` class is

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry registry )
    {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/user");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints( StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry )
    {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws");
    }

}
```

How can I obtain the WebSocket session id when the connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add this method in any class:

```
@EventListener
    private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        String sessionId = SimpAttributesContextHolder.currentAttributes().getSessionId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When STOMP session is connected, this piece of code is performed:

```
 else if (StompCommand.CONNECTED.equals(command)) {
        this.stats.incrementConnectedCount();
        accessor = afterStompSessionConnected(message, accessor, session);
        if (this.eventPublisher != null && StompCommand.CONNECTED.equals(command)) {
            try {
                SimpAttributes simpAttributes = new SimpAttributes(session.getId(), session.getAttributes());
                SimpAttributesContextHolder.setAttributes(simpAttributes);
                Principal user = getUser(session);
                publishEvent(this.eventPublisher, new SessionConnectedEvent(this, (Message<byte[]>) message, user));
            }
            finally {
                SimpAttributesContextHolder.resetAttributes();
            }
        }
    }
```

Pay attention to the `SessionConnectedEvent` to be listened with the `@EventListener` and also to that `SimpAttributesContextHolder`. You can get access to the `sessionId` in that event listener using a static API from the `SimpAttributesContextHolder`.

On the other hand the mentioned message in the event has a particular `simpSessionId` header for your consideration.

Comment: Artem Bilan, Where will this piece of code go? I just need to send messages through sockets to a specific user using `convertAndSendToUser(...)` using spring web socket session

Comment: OK. this is the part you didn't explain in your question. If you use that `convertAndSendToUser()`, then session is resolved automatically by the provided user.